# How to upload file with html button

Tags: html

I searched in google a lot but i cannot find anything. I tried ftp and alot of other things. I am new in html and i do not a lot. That is my code but i do not understand it at all:

```html
<form action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi"
enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<p>
Type some text (if you like):<br>
<input type="text" name="textline" size="30">
</p>
<p>
Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br>
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
</p>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I recommend learning _how to write in_ HTML or PHP before even attempting to upload a file to a server.